# "Class.Auth.AuthConfiguration: Ending position out of bounds" on Aloha Community Template LightningSelfRegistration

Tags: community

I created a Community using [Aloha template](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_community_identity_templates.pdf). I edited the Lightning component selfRegister that is being created by default to implement `forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes` so that I see it in Lightning Community Builder, which is the only modification I did to the code.

I added it to the Register page using Builder, but the self registration is not working on the custom component (the original standard one is working fine). I am getting this error:

> Ending position out of bounds: -1
>   Class.Auth.AuthConfiguration.: line 44, column 1 
>   Class.LightningSelfRegisterController.siteAsContainerEnabled

The method that seems to fail is this one:

```
private static boolean siteAsContainerEnabled(String communityUrl) {
    Auth.AuthConfiguration authConfig = new Auth.AuthConfiguration(communityUrl,'');
    return authConfig.isCommunityUsingSiteAsContainer();
}
```

And it is being called from @AuraEnabled selfRegister method in the LightningSelfRegisterController:

```
String networkId = Network.getNetworkId();

if(networkId != null && siteAsContainerEnabled(networkId)) {
    u.put('UserPreferencesHideS1BrowserUI',true);
}
```

I debugged the networkId and it is not null.

I guess it can be related to some config, but it seems weird, since the original Aloha selfRegistration component is working fine.

---

Config:

- We are using Person Accounts, they are working fine with the standard self registration component
- Community users and external users both have access to the apex controller

---

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue that Salesforce claimed it's already fixed, but I solved it with a workaround from this post -  [Error with Self-registration Lightning Component on Napili Community](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193212/error-with-self-registration-lightning-component-on-napili-community).