# Error with Self-registration Lightning Component on Napili Community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, napili, user-registration

I am trying to use the standard self-registration lightning component to get the capability for the external users to create a new user account in the community. 
On the Community's administration, I have already enabled : 'Allow external users to self-register', Chosen the **Register** community page, added my community profile and appended a temporary account.

Used the Lightning component: **selfRegister** on the Register community page. 
When I try to register with some test data, I am getting this error: **Ending position out of bounds: -1** I didn't made any changes to any of the code in the Ltng component or controller class. What I am doing wrong here? Just trying to make use of OOB functionality which is not working.

Referred this doc:

1. [Salesforce
   Self-Registration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.community_templates.meta/community_templates/rss_login_self_register.htm)

Screenshot: [image]

Some suggestions/references/workarounds would be really appreciated.

Comment: can you share a screenshot of your component settings? click on it in builder mode

Comment: Attached the screen for the component settings. Let me know if you need further info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright folks, I couldn't get this issue resolved here. So in my research, I found this issue as a **[Salesforce Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008t0OQAQ)** which was opened two weeks prior to my post.

As the fix was mentioned: **SCHEDULED - SPRING '18**, I have reached out to Salesforce to get this solved at least in my Org as this is a Standard functionality. Thanks to Salesforce, they guided me where to look and provided me with the code to fix it. Here it is:

**LightningSelfRegisterController.apxc**

> Use Network.getLoginUrl(networkId) or Network.communitiesLanding() to fetch the community url and then use it in the code to pass on instead of the networkId

```
String commURL = Network.getLoginUrl(networkId);

if(networkId != null && siteAsContainerEnabled(commURL)) { 
    u.put('UserPreferencesHideS1BrowserUI',true); 
}
```

Hope this helps someone who ran into this issue after Winter 18 release.

Comment: you changed your football team logo?

Comment: Haha I am in Washington Dc now. Lol. Dont know much how the redskins play, but wanted to have the regional feeling.